# Python TA-Lib using cython

Tags: python

I've a few threads here on Ta-Lib python installation. I have downloaded Cython and trying to do an easy_install but getting the below error:

```
talib.c:256:28: error: ta-lib/ta_libc.h: No such file or directory
talib.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_5talib_ACOS’:
talib.c:2391: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
talib.c:2502: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘TA_Initialize’
talib.c:2511: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘TA_ACOS_Lookback’
talib.c:2569: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘TA_ACOS’
talib.c:2578: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘TA_Shutdown’
talib.c:2587: error: ‘TA_SUCCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
talib.c:2587: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
talib.c:2587: error: for each function it appears in.)
talib.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_5talib_2AD’:
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the [TA-Lib python wrapper](http://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib) that uses Cython to wrap all the functions in TA-Lib, and released it on Github.  It works really well for me, uses Numpy arrays, is 2-4 times faster, more "pythonic", and easier to install (works on Mac OS X) than the SWIG interface.

It appears that you are not linking properly against the underlying `TA-Lib` C library -- have you installed that?  On Mac OS X, you can `brew install ta-lib`.  For other installation guidelines, look at [TA-Lib.org](http://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib)